# R SOCKet-based cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I am trying to establish a SOCKet cluster using the R `snow` package.

I have access to 5 machines with the IP addresses:
xxx.xxx.xx.x1
xxx.xxx.xx.x2
xxx.xxx.xx.x3
xxx.xxx.xx.x4
xxx.xxx.xx.x5

[As in this question](https://superuser.com/q/600658/133750), I have successfully copied the public key over to those machines so that password-less authentication works. From within R, this works

```
library(parallel)
library(snowfall)
for (i in seq.int(5)) system(print(paste('ssh ', 'root@xxx.xxx.xx.x', i, ' date',
                                  sep = '')))
```

However, this hangs.

```
sockCluster = makeSOCKcluster(c('root@xxx.xxx.xx.x1', 
                  'root@xxx.xxx.xx.x2',
                  'root@xxx.xxx.xx.x3',
                  'root@xxx.xxx.xx.x4',
                  'root@xxx.xxx.xx.x5'))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused that you say you're using the `snow` package, but the example loads `parallel` and `snowfall`.  That may have something to do with your problem, but there is also the issue of how to specify the remote user.

Snow always uses the ssh `-l` option with the value of the `user` option, which has a default value of `Sys.info()["user"]`.  It's possible that `makeSOCKcluster` is failing because the user is being specified in both ways, but that surprises me a bit.  I suggest that you try specifying only the `user` option:

```
library(snow)
sockCluster <- makeSOCKcluster(c('xxx.xxx.xx.x1', 
                  'xxx.xxx.xx.x2',
                  'xxx.xxx.xx.x3',
                  'xxx.xxx.xx.x4',
                  'xxx.xxx.xx.x5'), user='root')
```

Comment: `parallel` subsumes `snow` and `multicore`.

Comment: @fgnu But `makeSOCKcluster` is defined in `snow`.  If you want to use `parallel`, you should use `makePSOCKcluster` instead. And `snow` is still necessary if you want to use an MPI cluster, so it's not completely subsumed by `parallel`.